# How can I access website on Mac localhost PHP server from an iPhone on the same network?

Tags: php, server, localhost

My Mac's IP is 192.168.1.122, the server is on port 8000. I've tried to connect to it from my iPhone with

```
http://192.168.1.122:8000/index.php
http://<name>.local:8000/index.php
both of the above without the "http://"
```

Note that going to

```
http://<name>.local
```

works, showing a page that says "It works!"

How can I view the site file on the iPhone?

EDIT: http://localhost:8000/index.php works on the Mac as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out based on a similar but different question:

Open the PHP server using the command

```
$ php -S 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Then, you can access it from any browser on any device connected to the same network by typing in host computer's IP:8000, NOT 0.0.0.0:8000